# Java Spring boot Service bean creation order

Tags: java, service, spring-boot

In Spring boot application I use several beans with annotated with `@Service`. I want that one of this beans will be created after the all other service beans was created.
How can I do it?

Comment: What is the reason for it?

Comment: You could use @DependsOn("some-bean")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spring uses the dependencies of your services to determine the order in which it creates your services.

If you want finer control about when your services are created (i.e. create one service after all others, even though it doesn't have all the dependencies), then you can use [SmartLifeCycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html).

This class allows you to define different phases for initializing (and also destroying) your beans. See also [Startup and shutdown callbacks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor) in the Spring Framework documentation.