# Autoconfiguration with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to create one bean that will be execute before Spring Boot create my connection, so I have this 2 @Config to create my dbs

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbregistroEntityManagerFactory",basePackages = {"br.com.lumera.repositories.registro"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbRegistroConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dbRegistroDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.dbregistro")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbregistroEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbregistroEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dbRegistroDataSource") DataSource dbRegistroDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dbRegistroDataSource)
                .packages("br.com.lumera.entity.registro")
                .persistenceUnit("dbregistro")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "dbregistroTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager dbRegistroTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dbregistroEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory)
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

AND

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", basePackages = {"br.com.lumera.repositories.dnaso"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbDnasoConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.dnaso")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbdnasoEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("br.com.lumera.entity.dnaso")
                .persistenceUnit("dbdnaso")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager dbRegistroTransactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory)
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

Then I create my class with autoconfigurate:

```
@Component
@AutoConfigureOrder
@ConditionalOnClass(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="dbdanso.flyway")
@AutoConfigureBefore(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class FlywayConf {
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Bean
    public Boolean teste(){
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portalservicos","postgres","dna44100");
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration/dbdnaso");
        flyway.migrate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

but he execute after my DbRegistroConfig and DbDnasoConfig anyone can help me ?

Comment: Look at this link: [Spring Boot auto configuration order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692905/spring-boot-auto-configuration-order).  In particular, note that "... @AutoConfigureOrder is just another means to order auto-configurations, not the instantiation of beans they create".  See also [Spring Boot Service Bean Creation Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874095/java-spring-boot-service-bean-creation-order)

Comment: Doesn't configuration always occur before components?  You are trying to create the flywayConf bean before the Configuration beans. I think in order to make that happen, you will need to create the flywayConf bean within a class also marked with Configuration and then handle order from there.

Comment: basically you want to execute the FlaywayConf before DbRegistroConfig and DbDnasoConfig. Is that right?

Comment: @Hareesh correct. I think to execute in primaryDataSource() or  secondaryDataSource(), but will be better if I separate :D tks

Answer (score 1):

Spring does't bother about whether its a AutoConfiguration or normal POJO class. It just looks for the Configurations and it creates the beans based on the configuration given at the bean level.

To run *FlywayConf* before the  *DbRegistroConfig* and *DbDnasoConfig*,add [@DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) Annoatation @Bean level of the  *DbRegistroConfig* and *DbDnasoConfig*.